# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : PagedListPager ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, pagedlist, veracode

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app, and I am using `X.PagedList` to do paging.

In my table I set this for Paging

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.SearchResultViewPaging, page => 
         Url.Action("ResultPaging", "Participant", new { page = page }))
```

The method in the controller is decorated with a `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` annotation. I have this as a warning of Veracode.

In Javascript, this is the call I use to send

```
headers: {
            "RequestVerificationToken":
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
         },
```

How can I send this as a header?

Thanks

Comment: Could you tell me what you want ? you want fix the warning or implement Antiforgery in webapi ?

Comment: I want to implement ValidateAntiForgeryToken in the controller method, so I need to send  a header in the pagination... I think it is the only way... thanks

Comment: Since X.PagedList is 3rd package, pls wait, I will investigate the issue next week.

Comment: Hi Diego, [does the link useful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42652024/7687666) ?